# Trying to print two color stacked barh using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, group-by

I want a stacked horizontal bar graph showing red for bad and green for good for each system change request (CR). The # is the count of good/bad CRs by system:

My data:

```
system                      assessment #

ALPHA                       bad     4
                            good    2
BRAVO                       good   55
                            bad    28
CHARLIE                     bad     3
DELTA                       bad     4
```

I tried

```
chart = gb.plot.barh(color=chart_colors, stacked=True)
```

and

```
gb = df.groupby(group_by).assessment.value_counts(
                        ).unstack(level=-1).nlargest(limit,columns='bad').stack()


rbar = [x for x in gb.unstack(level=-1)['bad']]
gbar = [x for x in gb.unstack(level=-1)['good]]

#     
chart = plt.barh(0, rbar, color='r')
chart = plt.barh(1, gbar, left=rbar, color='g')

plt.show()
```

What I want to show is good/bad by system.

Note that when I gb.unstack(-1) I get

```
system        owner       good assmt    bad assessment
ALPHA         Alice               35                45
BRAVO         Bob                 15                25
CHARLIE       Charly               7                17
DELTA         David               15                10
```

The goal is to sort the results by the top 5 or so bad assessments and produce a graph:

```
ALPHA    BBBBBBBBBGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
BRAVO    BBBBBBBGGGGGGGG
CHARLIE  BBBBBGGGGGG
etc.
```

So far I have not been able to do this with a groupby object, but feel I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly then here's my solution:

```
# Given
df = pd.DataFrame({'system':['Alpha', 'Bravo', 'Charlie'],
                  'good#':[10, 3, 0],
                  'bad#': [5, 6, 4]})
df
   bad# good#   system
0   5   10      Alpha
1   6   3       Bravo
2   4   0       Charlie

df = df.sort_values('bad#', ascending=False)
df
   bad# good#   system
1   6   3       Bravo
0   5   10      Alpha
2   4   0       Charlie

df.set_index('system').plot(kind='barh', stacked=True)
```

[image: plt]

Comment: That works, but if you do a group_by, you get a group_by object and I haven't figured out how to get it to work. (thanks!)